# Drupal 7: hierarchy disabled setting on taxonomy vocabulary

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I would like to disable taxonomy hierarchy for a vocabulary.
In older versions of Drupal there used to be a setting on the vocabulary page:

> Hierarchy: disabled

Can do I achieve this with Drupal 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to do it. I ended up using hook_form_FORM_ID_alter on the taxonomy form in the admin area, like so:

```
function hook_form_taxonomy_overview_terms_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {    
        $form['#parent_fields'] = FALSE;
}
```